# how to run a test class that will continue to work after executing the main method

Tags: java, selenium

I have a test class in which the maine executes code in which I get test data that I have to use in my test, how to make the maine method run first, and then the rest of the code in the class. If I run the class through testng.xml then the main method doesn’t even start at all. And if I run main, the rest of the code just doesn’t start either

```
package testClassPackage;

public class testWeatherChrome {
    public static String parcedData;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String sURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/?q=Odessa,ua&APPID=518a64dd48106aa542464d3bd94d12ce"; //just a string


        URL url = new URL(sURL);
        URLConnection request = url.openConnection();
        request.connect();


        JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) request.getContent()));
        JsonObject rootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray message = rootobj.get("list").getAsJsonArray();
        Map<String, String> data = new TreeMap<>();

        for (JsonElement lst : message) {
            JsonObject lstObject = lst.getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject el = (JsonObject) lstObject.get("main");
//            System.out.println(lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString() + " " + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            if (lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString().contains(" 12")) {

                data.put("Дата " + lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString(), "Прогноз День:" + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            } else if (lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString().contains(" 21")) {
                data.put("Дата " + lstObject.get("dt_txt").getAsString(), "Прогноз Ночь:" + el.get("temp").getAsString());
            }

        }
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type gsonType = new TypeToken<TreeMap>() {
        }.getType();
        String gsonData = gson.toJson(data, gsonType);
        parcedData = gsonData;
        System.out.println("main");

    }
        @BeforeClass
        public void setUp () {
            initDriver.getInstance("chrome");
        }

    @Test
    public void getTitle() throws InterruptedException {
        String URL ="https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=ru&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin";
        initDriver.driver.get(URL);
        initDriver.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"identifierId\"]")).sendKeys("lesha.test111@gmail.com");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=\"Далее\"]")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(initDriver.driver, 10);
        WebElement passwordElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")));
//        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"password\"]")).sendKeys("Leshasugurov222");
        passwordElement.sendKeys("Leshasugurov222");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()=\"Далее\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"Почта\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()=\"Написать\"]")).click();
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@aria-label=\"Кому\"]")).sendKeys("leshaa.test333@gmail.com");
        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@aria-label=\"Тема\"]")).sendKeys("Погода на неделю для Одессы");
        System.out.println(WeatherParse.parcedData);
//        initDriver.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria-label=\"Тело письма\"]")).sendKeys(WeatherParse.parcedData);


    }


//    @AfterClass
//    public void close() {
//        initDriver.quit();
//    }

}
```

Comment: it would serve you well to read up a decent tutorial on JUnit. You're not supposed to have a main method in test classes, for one

Comment: Move you main method code to  @BeforeClass so that it executes before your test..

Comment: call you main method in the setup method.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the **testng.xml**, it's obvious that the testng.xml file will not respect the main method (as it was not meant to be).

**Solution:**

1) Use `@BeforeSuite` annotation and execute your priority tasks.

2) You can also use your testng.xml file and define your test sequence accordingly.